# Running multi-class game with HTML

Tags: java, html, eclipse, applet, classnotfoundexception

I have a project that has 16 classes. I can run it in Eclipse with no problem. But when trying to export it to a Runnable Jar, the resulting Executable Jar File doesn't do anything when run. So, I created an html file with an applet. But now I get an error when the page loads: 
ClassNotFoundException
finalGame.Testing.class

My game does utilize a local highscore feature so I'm thinking that might be the problem, but wouldn't that mean the exception would be the highscore class. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You export it to a JAR, and you get an EXE? Something is off here...

Comment: How are you creating the JAR? If you're running a .exe that's your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your eclipse version, there is usually a way to right-click on a project, export it as runnable jar file. The dialog generally asks for a location of where to save the runnable .jar file and whether you want to package libraries inside or not.